# why i see in log error 206 or 404 when user watch videos on my site?

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, jwplayer

I use nginx, jw player and sometimes i see those error 206 and 404. But usually, response is 200.
my log:

XX.XX.XX.XX - - [15/Apr/2013:21:23:40 +0400] "GET /route/86258d45ffc3403789b73e5ff2af83ce/106/video.flv HTTP/1.1" 206 1 "http://example.com/course/36/files/106/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; ru-ru; GT-P5100 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30"

I red about error 206 - partial content. But I don't understand when and why it's happend?

Comment: Very weird, do you have an example link that we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status 206 (or any other status from 200 to 299) is not an error. It indicates a [partial content response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7) which is sent if the client requests it. Since it's a video, I'm guessing the user skipped part of the video and so the player software on the client sent a partial request for the rest of it.

Comment: May it status (206) appear becuse user download a video?